# Is there any thread safe variable for Pthreads, i need to pass data from one thread to other

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Im new to implementation of pthreads

Im using pthreads for two separate actions but in some cases i will have to use data updated from first thread to be used by the other, so just a global variable, with mutex will work or is there any particular variable to be used?

Another thing is that how can i make a pthreads wait until a particular condition is achieved, now i use a "if" condition, but here, thread will be running continuously(Utilizing system recourses) and if condition is satisficed that piece of code works

I was looking for something like an interrupt is it possible?

similarly stopping a pthread,  should i use pthreadexit?

Comment: I think all of your three (!) questions are answered by any tutorial for POSIX threads ("pthreads").  Please don't ask multiple questions in one. Please don't use SO as a substitute for a tutorial, which it isn't intended to be. Please try to locate existing answers before asking the same question again. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Mutex + variable is sufficient. For second part of your question, please read about conditionals and how to use it with pthread (good start point can be https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)

Comment: Condition variables are probably the worst place to start learning about POSIX threads.  Getting the interaction between predicates, condition variables, and mutexes correct is hard enough without having to do the required handling of spurious wakeups.   Locking/unlocking mutexs or posting to/waiting on semaphores is a ***lot*** simpler.